# Running laravel migration on heroku server

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5, heroku-postgres

I have a production server, and i have deployed the code into the server, but when i try to migrate the databse with this command :

```
heroku run php artisan
```

This what i have returned

```
Running php artisan on [app-name] ... up, run.3899
bash: php: command not found
```

And the `BUILDPACK_URL` in the Config Vars set to

`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php`

any help please :) ?

Comment: Is PHP installed on the machine?

Comment: @Skytiger i have deployed the same project into heroku before, and php was installed in the server, but this time i got this error from heroku.

so php is not installed as it seems

Comment: [If you're looking for a way to check, you can try this](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/php/how-to-check-php-installed-detect-php-version.html)

Comment: try to run first: `heroku run bash`, and when run you command